# Understanding padding left and position absolute in React native , layouting questions

Tags: react-native

After experimenting with the padding property in react native i got the following findings:

### Question 1

- padding-left: 150 works
- padding-left; 150pd crashes
- padding-left; 150px works ( guess it ignores px and works as 1? )

---

- padding: 150 crashes
- padding : 150dp crashes
- padding : 150px works ( guess it ignores px and works as 1? )

This makes little sense to me especially since scenario 1 works but scenario 6 doesnt!
In any case it looks as if i should abandon padding as a shorthand entirely, and write padding-left/right/bottom/top everytime, right?

### Question 2

As far as i understand, `left/right/bottom and top` are essentially absolute positions to the parent component ( i got this after lots of trial and error ) This happens without specifying `position:absolute`.An example

If there's a parent container with unspecified height you cant make it resize itself by using `left/bottom/*` on the child. You need to use padding.

The question is, when would i ever need to use `position:absolute` given that `left/right/*` already do that for me anyway. And is there any other difference im missing between `left` and `padding-left`?

### Question 3

In general, for the layouting part, the connection with the web side of things isnt instant for me. Is there a better guide to understanding how things actually work and not guesstimating like i do right now? Im using https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#left but it doesnt really explain things very well in layouting terms.. Any pointers appreciated

Comment: Well, one obvious difference is that when you use padding, the child is touchable and the background is drawn also in the padded area. So absolute positioning is more like margin. If you don't want to overflow the parent container I would not use  position:absolute at all, but it might be useful in some cases where you need to do that. 

Regarding the first question all sizes should be given as plain numbers without dp/px/etc., and they are rendered as device-independent pixels. If you really need to size things with pixels check out PixelRatio.

Comment: isnt it odd though that the plain padding property and its shorthand notation of padding: a b c d works only by attaching px to it? I guess its a specific case that doesnt align with the rest..

Comment: if you are trying to use the shorthand `padding: [top] [right] [bottom] [left]` like in css, that's not valid in React Native, and should produce an error, or at the very least just not do anything. The padding style sets the same padding for all sides, so if you need to set different sizes for each side, you'd need to use paddingLeft, paddingRight, etc. In any case, using 'px' should not be a thing in React Native as far as I'm aware.